# Combine two lists into a single dictionary or Print them (shortest way)

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two lists

```
a=[0,0.3,0.6]
b=['x','y','z']
```

I can use zip to combine them into dictionary, iterate through it (Also for some reason zip change order of a). But I am wondering the shortest code (one liner), that takes a,b and prints out

```
0 \t 'x'
0.3 \t 'y'
0.6 \t 'z'
```

Comment: Dictionaries are not ordered

Comment: `zip()` does *not* change the order of the inputs. Perhaps you are confused about the inputs you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use zip, but no dictionaries:

```
print '\n'.join('{} \t {}'.format(aa,bb) for aa,bb in zip(a,b))
```

or

```
print '\n'.join(map('{0[0]} \t {0[1]}'.format, zip(a,b)))
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way you're going to create a dict is with a comprehension (with zip though...)

```
{key: value for (key, value) in zip(a,b)}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easy with `zip`:

```
print '\n'.join(str(i)+' \t '+str(j) for i, j in zip(a, b))
```

Or:

```
print '\n'.join('%d \t %s' % (i, j) for i, j in zip(a, b))
```

Or of course the formatting that [eumiro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14999954/1907098) used.

Answer (score 0):

`for/join/map` whatever you use, you are iterating at some level. List comprehension makes it compact (or 'shorter') and so is the `print`ing the `join`ed list. `map` also internally iterates over each element.

List comprehension:

```
[print("%d\t%d\n"%(i,j)) for i,j in zip(a,b)]
```

Comment: This only works in Python 3, and on top of that it's very bad style.

Comment: @Volatility, Can you please explain what is very bad in this?

Comment: List comps should be used to make lists, not to perform an action multiple times.